# Programmatically press "Right Shift" Key

Tags: c#, vb.net, keyboard

I'm having trouble with finding a way on how to press specifically a right shift key programmatically. I need a single key down and up (press/release).

What I have is:

```
SendKeys.Send("{RSHIFT}")
```

And I know that shift is like:

```
SendKeys.Send("+")
```

Which is just shift key, I suppose, but I need specifically a right shift key.

Could, someone, please, help me with this code?

Comment: I don't see any {RSHIFT} between the special keys recognized by [SendKeys.Send](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) and from what I can see in Send there is no way to recognize the right from the left shift key

Comment: YES! That's why I posted this question, to discover how to get the task done

Comment: Perhaps there is a different way to do your task. Why do you need to send a right shift key? Are you trying to communicate with another application?

Comment: Yes and it requires specifically Right Shift key

Comment: I've updated my previous answer, check out the new one.

Answer (score 6):

Using the keybd_event you don't need window handle

VB :

```vb
Public Class MyKeyPress
    <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
    Public Shared Sub keybd_event(ByVal bVk As UInteger, ByVal bScan As UInteger, ByVal dwFlags As UInteger, ByVal dwExtraInfo As UInteger)
    End Sub


    ' To find other keycodes check bellow link
    ' http://www.kbdedit.com/manual/low_level_vk_list.html
    Public Shared Sub Send(key As Keys)
        Select Case key
            Case Keys.A
                keybd_event(&H41, 0, 0, 0)
            Case Keys.Left
                keybd_event(&H25, 0, 0, 0)
            Case Keys.LShiftKey
                keybd_event(&HA0, 0, 0, 0)
            Case Keys.RShiftKey
                keybd_event(&HA1, 0, 0, 0)
            Case Else
                Throw New NotImplementedException()
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

C#:

```cs
public static class MyKeyPress
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern void keybd_event(uint bVk, uint bScan, uint dwFlags, uint dwExtraInfo);


    // To get other key codes check bellow link
    // http://www.kbdedit.com/manual/low_level_vk_list.html
    public static void Send(Keys key)
    {
        switch (key)
        {
            case Keys.A:
                keybd_event(0x41, 0, 0, 0);
                break;
            case Keys.Left:
                keybd_event(0x25, 0, 0, 0);
                break;
            case Keys.LShiftKey:
                keybd_event(0xA0, 0, 0, 0);
                break;
            case Keys.RShiftKey:
                keybd_event(0xA1, 0, 0, 0);
                break;
            default: throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```vb
MyKeyPress.Send(Keys.LShiftKey)
```

Answer (score 5):

[Found this after some creative keyword combinations](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dd6406e8-b6bf-4166-82a0-6d533def38a5/how-to-send-leftright-shift-key?forum=csharpgeneral)

It build down to this for sending keycodes:

```
Keys key = Keys.RShiftKey;//Right shift key  
SendMessage(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, (int)key, 1);
```

I don't know what the use case is here, but be mindful of the window handle parameter being passed: `Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle`.

This sends the keystroke to itself. If you are trying to send it to another process/program you will need to pass the window handle for that program.